Is it OK to edit a post to include a citation, rather than leaving a comment telling the author they should cite their source?
When reading a post, and notice that there is no citation for the source of an image or quoted text, my approach since getting full edit permission has been:

Have a quick search, and if can find the source of an image quoted text, then edit the post to include a link to the source. The most recent example is revision 2 in this. Having gone and found the source, might gain sufficient information to allow an answer to be created.
If can't quickly identify the source, leave a comment for the author asking them add a citation.

Having seen some questions where a moderator has closed a question without a citation, with the reason needs details or clarity, and left a comment to the author pointing them at the rules about the need to cite their sources, has made we wonder my if approach in 1) above is acceptable or not.

Thanks for asking. If someone else adds a missing reference for an OP, I have been surprised to learn from experience that this can actually cause problems, as I explain below. Therefore personally I do not want other people to add missing references. (Other useful links - yes! Missing references - no.)
Here's the problem:
If you (or another site member) adds the required reference(s) to a post where they are missing, rather than the OP doing it, then:

The OP has no incentive to learn about the site rules and they can claim (and some do) that they don't know references are required, when challenged.
We have already had it where other people (including me!) added missing references for OPs. But then the same OP (when challenged more strongly, when they again omitted references in future posts) then claimed they hadn't seen the previous comments telling them that it was required.    Because someone else (e.g. you or me) added the references, we can't prove that the OP did actually read the comments telling them when they missed those references in previous posts.
This adds to the work of keeping track of whether that OP has actually definitely been reminded of that site rule, which we try to do before taking stronger mod action in future.

Site members want to help answer questions, which is what we generally want, of course :)
However, questions which break the site rules should not be answered, which is why we can close them until they reach the required quality standard. For example, in the Help Center it says:

Answer well-asked questions
Not all questions can or should be answered here. {...}

As I have seen many times now, if we just leave a comment to an OP that they should add references to the copied material, site members will often still answer the question - without the OP adding the required reference(s).
That again means that the OP can claim they never saw the comments telling them about that requirement, so they repeat that infraction again (and again).
It also means that the OP has "got away" with not following the site rules, but has still got answer(s) to their question, because people want to help.
Do we really want to reward people who break the site rules, by getting their questions answered?
If we don't stop (well-meaning) site members from answering those questions which break the rules, by closing the question, then this problem that OPs still get answers even after breaking the rule on referencing, will continue to occur. That makes the site rule effectively meaningless, if OPs don't have to follow it.



Putting together those 2 points, I have been trialing the closure of unanswered questions with missing references, until the OP adds them. That deliberately puts the onus on the OP to fix their question, so that it complies with the site rules.
But to have the effect of teaching the OP about that site rule, it needs to be the OP who adds the required reference(s).

If you have a different process which will allow others to add the missing references and will still prove that the OP has seen and understood the requirement that they must add the references in future, then I'll be very glad to see if we can do that instead. However I couldn't think of one.
That is why I have been trialing the process I explained above, since that way we know the OP has definitely been reminded. But it only works if it is the OP, and not someone else, who adds the missing reference(s).

Background:
Just FYI, in case people didn't know, the requirement for correctly referencing copied or adapted material from elsewhere when posted onto Stack Exchange, is stated:

In a separate rule: "How to reference material written by others".
To be clear, that applies to questions, answers & comments. See here & here.

In the Code of Conduct - Inauthentic usage policy:

{...} we do not allow what we define as inauthentic usage of our systems, such as:
{...}

Plagiarizing or copying content from websites, books, or other online and offline tools without proper attribution in a manner that violates our referencing standards.



In the site's Terms of Service about Subsciber Content:

{...} all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.




Having seen The return of Staging Ground to Stack Overflow, if new Electrical Engineering users had an option for a Staging Ground, perhaps part of the review process could be to check the rules on referencing material were understood. Perhaps having the rules explains in a private staging area would be more welcoming.

@ChesterGillon - Hi, "if new Electrical Engineering users had an option for a Staging Ground, perhaps part of the review process could be to check the rules on referencing material were understood." Agreed, good plan. However I haven't heard anything about SE sites other than SO getting Staging Ground, at the moment. || I have some other thoughts on how to improve visibility of that rule, but it needs more work in the background before making it public (and might never happen).

I agree, but can do both editing and warning. I wouldn't put the onus on the user to enforce sources. It would be better for users to be better to edit if they have the source. If we want users to do proper editing then don't make them do modding also. If they need to they can flag the question for moderator attention.

@ChesterGillon I'll bet that feature gets moved site wide eventually.

@VoltageSpike - "I wouldn't put the onus on the user to enforce sources." Which user do you mean? The OP or another user who comes along later?

The user that wants to do the edits, it would be better to have the edit. The questions and answers are under a CC license so they are available to everyone

If we expect new users to learn and follow the rules, perhaps those rules belong in the tour, and not buried click after click deep.  Game this out a little bit -- make believe you're a new user, and do some new user stuff that you might do to learn the rules, and see where you first encounter the referencing rules.  Even if you manage to find our CoC, for example (which is a longshot, IMO), the reference rule can only be found by clicking through "Inauthentic Content" -- which is as meaningless a label as I've ever seen.

Your last link isn't even to our site.

@ScottSeidman - "Your last link isn't even to our site." If you mean the link embedded in the quote from the CoC then you're correct. But you'll see that I am correctly quoting from that page and its link. || If I didn't do that, I could get complaints that I'd not quoted it exactly. So whichever I do (change the link to our site or not), then someone could complain :( || If you mean the ToS link, then that is the official link. || Please give me some credit, Scott, I'm trying to give helpful links in my post.

@ScottSeidman - "the reference rule can only be found by clicking through "Inauthentic Content"" Not true, as it's also available under the first link I gave. IMHO it's less-than-optimal, though it seems SE don't see it that way, that the first link I gave is on the Help Center page for answering, not for asking and lots of OPs copy content into questions. || I do take the point about visibility and I do have an idea to possibly improve that visibility, as I said above to Chester - but we can't rename the CoC sections (e.g. "Inauthentic Content").

I was referring to the stackoverflow link, and you're right, that does appear at the bottom of our page.  There's nothing personal about this, and your efforts are appreciated, but the connotation that new users have everything they need to know and follow our rules just rings hollow, and certainly doesn't address the problem that new users don't know our rules.

Sam, the first link you give is to a subcategory in the full help center -- which would be at least three clicks deep from what I would think of as a "typical" new user experience, and that would be a conscientious new user who makes an above and beyond effort to learn the rules.  If we expect a new user to see something then it belongs somewhere in the tour.  After watching complaints from new users with closed questions for a decade, and responses to the the effect of "learn the rules", my conclusion is we're not adequately getting the rules to the new users.  That's not contentious.

.. and no, obviously we can't change CoC headings, but the powers that be can certainly look into fixing the new user on ramp, if they can tear themselves away from figuring out how to monetize our contributions.

@ScottSeidman - "the connotation that new users have everything they need to know" I never said that. I already said that IMHO rule visibility could be better (but if you emphasize all rules, then you really emphasize none). Much of what you are saying is (I believe) recognised by SE and they are looking at improving the "onboarding process" for new users. || New users are recommended to take the tour. The tour links to the help center. So while new users are not always reading the rules, many of them don't even read the tour when prompted! So SE do try to point users at the rules.

@ScottSeidman - Anyway, I can't fix all issues and I'm supposed to be doing other mod stuff that you'll see in due course, so I'll stop here. Thanks for the feedback, but please be realistic about what we can do locally. Many of your points would be better posted at Meta.SE as they affect the whole of SE.

@VoltageSpike - Thanks for that clarification. If I understand you correctly, your point is to follow the original status quo, allow new OPs to post questions without enforcing correct references & let people answer them (with, hopefully, someone telling the OP in a comment that they should add references). If so, please do post that as an answer, so we can highlight the issues with that approach too, as you have highlighted the issues with this one. || IMHO neither is perfect, both have different problems. || I plan to ask SE staff for advice but as you know, I'm doing something else first.

Thanks for this -- just to make explicit: we should vote-close questions needing sources as "needs clarification", and perhaps add a helpful comment to that effect as well (so that the asker and reviewers understand what exactly is missing, in case they haven't read this post)?  Or / and also, flag for moderator action?

@TimWilliams - Hi, At this stage I'm not asking anyone to change their actions - although if a question is missing references, then a site member adding a comment to the OP (if one hasn't been added already) can only help, thanks. || While I've been trialing a new process (to discover its pros & cons), it's clear that there are cons (as well as pros). I expect that getting guidance from SE staff will be needed, as I said to Voltage Spike, since it's their rules we're asked to enforce. || Meantime, there is an existing process which mods can follow for repeat referencing "offenders".

@SamGibson In MOSFET Datasheet Confusion I caused some confusion, in that in the First Questions review I selected Edit and entered a link to the datasheet just as you added a comment to the OP pointing out the rules about adding the required references. In future, I need to pay more attention to pointing out the rules as part of review tasks.

@ChesterGillon - Hi, I appreciate you helping & adding the link. As you said, I was typing my usual "please add the missing reference" comment to the OP at the same time. I deleted my comment when I saw you added the link. || The overall situation was exactly the problem I described in my answer here. You kindly added the link, which was the missing reference. But the OP might just think you added a link, without realising that they really, really should have included it themselves! || I added a "please do this in future" comment. The other problem is that not every OP would see, or heed

(cont'd) or perhaps understand an after-the-event comment, although that OP did. Anyway, thanks for your comment here and no harm done. I'm not keen to add extra work for site members like you to also have to explain the rules, when you're kindly going through the review queue. However unless an OP gets the message somehow that they should have included the required reference(s), then some can, and do, repeat that behaviour (whether due to a lack of understanding, or carelessness, or deliberately disobeying that rule). I am still planning to bring up this topic with SE staff for discussion.
